# Replace text with regexp in sublime text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, text-processing

How I replace text with part old text in sublime text.

I have:

```
<span class="foo">some text</span>
<span class="foo">another text</span>
```

I want:

```
<b>some text</b>
<b>another text</b>
```

Search

```
<span class="foo">(\w+)</span>
```

and replace with

```
{1}
```

don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search: `<span class="foo">(.*?)</span>`

Replace: `<b>$1</b>`

Comment: Thanks. I mistaken with replace argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use $1 instead of {1} for replacing text